# Panel Update after clicking the "Maximise/Minimise-Button" in the FormTaskbar

Tags: c#, .net

I have a panel with holds a Polygongraphic and i want it to get updated (adjustment of the size) if i click on the Maximise/Minimise-Button.

Is there a way to do so ?

I got it working for manually "pulling" the window in a different Size.
But i don't get it working for the Buttonclick.

Thanks for your help

Tobi

[Talking about this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiDuv.jpg)

Comment: How are you handling the dragging?  It should be a handler on the WM_SIZE event.

Comment: Im handling the dragging with the ResizeEnd event.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?  WinForms should attach to the `Resize`  event handler.  I've just tried it, and it the event fires for both maximise/minimise and resize.

Comment: Its winForms. I tried it with the resident Event but noting happend...but thanks for your help 